# why I can't get multiple spaces in *?

Tags: c, sizeof, fgets, c-strings

```
int main()
{

    int input;
    printf("input lenth : \n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    while(getchar()!='\n')
        continue;
    printf("input str : \n");
    char* sentence = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * input);
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
    reverse(sentence, strlen(sentence));
    free(sentence);
    return 0;
}
```

I learn `fgets` can get space.

so I `malloc` enough space to `sentence` ex) 100

and I input `I am a boy`

But when I print my `sentence`, IT just print `I am a` ...

what's th problem?

Comment: One problem is you aren't allocating enough memory.  Remember, you need 1 extra character to hold the null character `'\0'` that terminates the string.  Also, `fgets` stores the newline as well, so that's 2 extra characters the you need to allocate.  Also, you can't use `sizeof(sentence)` for the buffer size.  That's just the size of a pointer.  Use `input + 2` for both the `malloc` argument and the `fgets` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
fgets(sentence, input, stdin);
```

Otherwise `sizeof( sentence )` will yield the size of a pointer declared like

```
char* sentence = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * input);
```

Pay attention to that the function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string. You should remove it like

```
sentence[ strcspn( sentence, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
```

It gives you size of pointer char i.e. 8 (Depends on 32 & 64 system you use).
So you are able to receive 7 characters only as fgets assignes '\0' character to last character.

So, use length you received from the user i.e. 100.

```
fgets(sentence, input, stdin);
```